# Is there any way to cast timedelta64 to int64 in numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, timedelta

For example, I have a piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

d = np.array(['2001-01-01T12:00', '2002-02-03T13:56:03.172'],
              dtype='datetime64')

@njit
def datetime_operand(date):
    x = date[1] - date[0]
    return x


datetime_operand(d) // the result is numpy.timedelta64(34394163172,'ms')
```

Simple option to type `np.int64(x)` doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try to add .astype(int) at end

Comment: Yes, the first thing. Unfortunately, numba doesn't allow to use .astype and similiar things in njit mode.

Comment: What is the result you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the result you look for, but I suppose pandas can help here:

```
import pandas
@njit
def datetime_operand(date):
    df = pandas.DataFrame(d.T)
    df[0]=pd.to_datetime(df[0])
    return (df[0].iloc[1]-df[0].iloc[0]).to_numpy()
```

The result is like this:

```
datetime_operand(d)
umpy.timedelta64(34394163172,'ms')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't possible to use pandas in njit mode

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is:

```
import numpy as np
dt64 = np.datetime64('2009-01-01')
print((dt64 — np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's'))
```

Comment: so, what's the relation to `numba`?